# Insert trigger subtract value from another table

Tags: php, sql

I am a newbie at sql. I made a php website that user can make item purchases. And now I want to make a trigger for when a receipt is created, it subtracts the quantity in the item stock table with the quantity sold in the receipt.

```
create table if not exists Store.Receipt (
ReceiptID varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
ItemID varchar(10) NOT NULL,
PriceSold int NOT NULL,
QtySold int NOT NULL,
RDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
BranchID varchar(10) NOT NULL,
EmployeeID varchar(10) NOT NULL,
MemberID varchar(10) DEFAULT "NotMember",
primary key (ReceiptID, ItemID));

alter table Store.Receipt
add constraint FK_Receipt_Member foreign key (MemberID)
references Store.MemberShip (MemberID),
add constraint FK_Receipt_Employee foreign key (EmployeeID)
references Store.Employee (EmployeeID),
add constraint FK_Receipt_Branch foreign key (BranchID)
references Store.Branch (BranchID)
on delete restrict
on update cascade;
```

The sql script above is for the receipt table. The id for this table is auto generated using autoincrement. One ReceiptID can contain many items. So I am using a composite of ReceiptID and ItemID sold as the primary key. And here is the Script for the table.

```
create table if not exists Store.Item (
ItemID varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
ItemName varchar(45) NOT NULL,
UnitPrice int NOT NULL,
QtyStock int NOT NULL,
SupplierID varchar(10) NOT NULL,
primary key (ItemID));

alter table Store.Item
add constraint FK_Supplier foreign key (SupplierID)
references Store.Supplier (SupplierID)
on delete restrict
on update cascade;
```

I have been trying to make the trigger on my own, but I am still quite unfimiliar with sql triggers. Here is what I came up with.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_stock_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON Store.Receipt
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE 
@qty numeric
@itemid varchar

@itemid = SELECT ItemID FROM Receipt WHERE ReceiptID = INSERTED.ItemID;
@qty = SELECT QtySold FROM Receipt WHERE ReceiptID = INSERTED.QtySold;

  UPDATE Item SET QtyStock = QtyStock - @qty WHERE ItemID = @itemid;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Hi, I am running the sql script on phpmyadmin. The problem is that I am not sure how to make the trigger to achieve the purpose I want. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the trigger needs to be quite so complicated as you can access the values required directly by prefixing the column name with `NEW`

```
create trigger `update_stock_trigger` 
    after insert on `receipt` 
    for each row 
    begin
        update `item` set `qtystock` = `qtystock` - new.qtysold where `itemid` = new.itemid;
    end
```

Using a slightly simplified schema ( remove FK dependency upon `Supplier` table )

```
mysql> describe item;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ItemID     | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| ItemName   | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| UnitPrice  | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| QtyStock   | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| SupplierID | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+


mysql> describe receipt;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-----------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default   | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-----------+-------+
| ReceiptID  | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI | 0         |       |
| ItemID     | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL      |       |
| PriceSold  | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL      |       |
| QtySold    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL      |       |
| RDate      | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL      |       |
| BranchID   | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL      |       |
| EmployeeID | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL      |       |
| MemberID   | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NotMember |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-----------+-------+
```

And populated a single Product in the `item` table

```
mysql> select * from item;
+--------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
| ItemID | ItemName | UnitPrice | QtyStock | SupplierID |
+--------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
| 1      | bob      |        23 |      100 | 404-blah   |
+--------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
```

And an initial record in the `receipt` table

```
mysql> select * from receipt;
+-----------+--------+-----------+---------+---------------------+----------+------------+-----------+
| ReceiptID | ItemID | PriceSold | QtySold | RDate               | BranchID | EmployeeID | MemberID  |
+-----------+--------+-----------+---------+---------------------+----------+------------+-----------+
| 1         | 1      |        43 |      17 | 2020-01-30 09:28:29 | Dundee   | Senga-X    | NotMember |
+-----------+--------+-----------+---------+---------------------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

and a subsequent second record ( showing used sql )

```
INSERT INTO `Store`.`receipt` (`ReceiptID`, `ItemID`, `PriceSold`, `QtySold`, `RDate`, `BranchID`, `EmployeeID`) 
    VALUES ('2', '1', '35', '10', '2020-01-30 09:32:00', 'Glasgow', 'Senga-Y');
```

The trigger has updated the `item` table accordingly

```
mysql> select * from item;
+--------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
| ItemID | ItemName | UnitPrice | QtyStock | SupplierID |
+--------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
| 1      | bob      |        23 |       73 | 404-blah   |
+--------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If I were to do the opposite, say I delete a receipt. To restore the quantity sold back to the stock I would have to use a trigger before delete right? @RamRaider

Comment: you could use a trigger yes

Comment: I notice that none of your questions have ever been `"accepted"` by you or `"upvoted"` - perhaps you ought to consider the worth that answers provided might impart - a process that has benefits for all parties.

Comment: Thank you @RamRaider. I am still quite new to the stackoverflow community, will do it in the future.